# Android check device running time since last reboot

Tags: android

I wonder is there a way to get the time that the device has been running since last reboot?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html

```
SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
```

> elapsedRealtime() and elapsedRealtimeNanos() return the time since the system was booted, and include deep sleep. This clock is guaranteed to be monotonic, and continues to tick even when the CPU is in power saving modes, so is the recommend basis for general purpose interval timing.

Answer (score 10):

Per the answer to this [other question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/95753/how-to-know-how-long-my-smartphone-is-running):

Go to `Settings`>`About Phone`>`Status` and scroll to the end of the options. You'll see the up time.

Comment: On Pie, the status did not count reboot uptime instead, it counts shutdown uptime. Simple meaning is that, if your phone is turn on exactly 5 hours with 2 times reboot in between, the up time is exactly 5 hours.

Comment: On Android 11, the status does indeed counts the uptime since last reboot. I just restarted my phone.